# Vue.js/javascript create new object onclick, with one value being the value of the list item you clicked on

Tags: javascript, vue.js, key-value, listitem, v-for

I have an array of types, that I am displaying as a list using v-for. When the user clicks on one of the list items, I want to create a new object in the allFields object of that type, meaning that the value in the first key-value pair should be whatever "type" the user clicked on. Is this possible and if not, what is a better way to go about this? Thanks in advance!

```
<ul>
   <li v-for="type in types" @click="addNew">{{ type }}</li>
</ul>


new Vue ({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
      types: [
        'date',
        'number',
        'currency',
        'text'
      ],
      allFields: {

      }
    },
    methods: {
      addNew: function () {
        this.allFields = Object.assign({}, this.allFields, {
          field1: {
            'type': '?????',
            'label': ''
          }
        });
      },
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass an argument to your `addNew` function

## Passing the value

```
<ul>
   <li v-for="type in types" @click="addNew(type)">{{ type }}</li>
</ul>


new Vue ({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
      types: [
        'date',
        'number',
        'currency',
        'text'
      ],
      allFields: {

      }
    },
    methods: {
      addNew: function (type) {
        this.allFields = Object.assign({}, this.allFields, {
          field1: {
            'type': type,
            'label': ''
          }
        });
      },
    }
  });
```

## Passing the key

```
<ul>
   <li v-for="(type, key) in types" @click="addNew(key)">{{ type }}</li>
</ul>


new Vue ({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
      types: [
        'date',
        'number',
        'currency',
        'text'
      ],
      allFields: {

      }
    },
    methods: {
      addNew: function (key) {
        this.allFields = Object.assign({}, this.allFields, {
          field1: {
            'type': this.types[key],
            'label': ''
          }
        });
      },
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also add an extra attribute and access it in you method. I've added the `allFields` variable to show, that it works.

```js
new Vue ({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      types: [
        'date',
        'number',
        'currency',
        'text'
      ],
      allFields: {
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    addNew(e) {
      // access type attribute
      const type = e.target.type;
      // generate a name
      const name = `${type}-${Object.keys(this.allFields).map(key => key === type).length}`;

      this.allFields = Object.assign({}, this.allFields, {
        [name]: {
          'type': type,
          'label': ''
        }
      });
    },
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.0.3/vue.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>JS Bin</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <ul>
        {{allFields}}
        <li v-for="type in types" @click="addNew" :type="type">{{ type }}</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

One addition. Maybe you want to go the fancy ES6 way and use the `spread operator`. Then you have to do this:

**Change:**

```
this.allFields = Object.assign({}, this.allFields, {
  [name]: {
    'type': type,
    'label': ''
  }
});
```

**to:**

```
this.allFields = {
  ...this.allFields, // spread operator
  [name]: {
    'type': type,
    'label': ''
  }
}
```